# robot formation in ROS

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm going to work with ground mobile robot formation in ROS, using turtlebot to do some experiments in simulator like stage. However, there's a tough problem.

The velocity command in ROS is made up of linear velocity and angular velocity while a vast number of formation algorithms result in velocity in 2D vector. Is there any method to make a translation? What if the algorithm generates target point to each robot? How to generate ROS velocity,namely Twist, to make diff-drive robots like turtlebot arrive in such points. I don't think using navigation stack is a good idea.

I'd appreaciate it if anyone can give me some advice or some related package in ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229906/robot-formation-in-ros/) by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you think that the navstack is not a good idea because you need to update your goals at a high frequency, I suggest you look at [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/28950/what-is-the-best-way-to-follow-a-moving-target/) which discusses how to follow a moving target - the "target points" of each robot in your case.

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0